# How to log messages to the console and a file both in golang?

Tags: go

I can direct all messages to `log.txt` file:

```
logFile, err := os.OpenFile("log.txt", os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND | os.O_RDWR, 0666)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
log.SetOutput(logFile)
```

But how can I get log messages in console too?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Use an [`io.MultiWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter)

> MultiWriter creates a writer that duplicates its writes to all the provided writers, similar to the Unix tee(1) command

```
logFile, err := os.OpenFile("log.txt", os.O_CREATE | os.O_APPEND | os.O_RDWR, 0666)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
mw := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, logFile)
log.SetOutput(mw)
```

The only change was

```
mw := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, logFile)
```

Comment: not foget `logFile.Close()` before program exit.