# Log Data of io.Writer

Tags: go, streamwriter, writer

I'd like to create a method that takes a ìo.Writer`and wraps a`cipher.StreamWriter` around, to encrypt the writer. For Debugging Reasons, I'd like to print out what data passes the writer. How do I achieve this?

The Crypto Code is just placeholder, so fixed key, iv and so on is just for testing things out.

```
func NewEncryptionWriter(w io.Writer) io.WriteCloser {
    key, _ := hex.DecodeString("6368616e676520746869732070617373")
    c, _ := aes.NewCipher(key)
    iv := make([]byte, aes.BlockSize)
    return &cipher.StreamWriter{S: cipher.NewOFB(c, iv), W: w}
}
```

Comment: I guess you'll need yet another wrapper, that implements `io.WriterCloser`, prints out the data and delegates the rest to the wrapped writer.

Comment: Possible duplicates, writing to multiple io.Writers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719525/how-to-log-messages-to-the-console-and-a-file-both-in-golang/36719588#36719588, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351208/read-contents-from-what-io-writer-writes/45351271#45351271, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326997/how-to-pipe-stdout-from-os-exec-to-file-and-to-terminal/48327112#48327112,

Comment: @JimB you are absolutely right, didn't find them before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [MultiWriter](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiWriter) from io package: it creates a writer that duplicates its writes to all the provided writers, similar to the Unix tee(1) command.